# Install build tools 25.0.3 error showing in android studio when i tried to run my old android project

Tags: android, build, installation, appcompatactivity

I uninstalled and installed again the android studio due to some errors on building gradle.The projects that i already created and run successfully,are now not working with my currently installed studio.It red marks the lines AppCompatActivity,findViewById,startActivity etc.

the full java file is as follows

```
package com.example.mfk.simpleloginapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static EditText username;
    private static EditText password;
    private static TextView attempts;
    private static Button login_btn;
    int attempt_counter = 5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        LoginButton();
    }

    public void LoginButton()
    {
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4_Enter_UN_Here);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3_Enter_PW_Here);
        attempts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText5_Attmpts_see_here);
        login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2_Login);

        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));

        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(username.getText().toString().equals("mohammedfarisk")&&password.getText().toString().equals("farisk321@android"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Username and Password are correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.mfk.user.User");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Username or Password is NOT correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    attempt_counter--;
                    attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                    if(attempt_counter == 0)
                    {

                        login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
             });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //inflates the menu ; this adds items to the acion bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed build tools 25.0.3?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: How can i identify whether i installed build tools 25.0.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no option to install it automatically, look for this button:
[image: SDK Manager] (SDK Manager).